How to add span to where cursor is in a div?
I have a Vue component, "Add Dynamic Variable". It consumes the prop "targetElementId" which is the text input (a div with contenteditable), and it has a dropdown, which when selected, adds a green span (dynamic variable label) to the input. How can I get it to add the variable where the typing cursor is instead of the end of the element?
<template>
  <div class="relative inline-flex items-center">
    <button type="button" @click="toggleDropdown" class="inline-flex items-center gap-x-1.5 rounded-full bg-green-100 hover:bg-green-50 px-2 py-1 text-xs font-medium text-green-700">
      <BoltIcon class="h-3 w-3 fill-green-700" viewBox="0 0 12 12" aria-hidden="true"></BoltIcon>
      Add Dynamic Variable
    </button>
    <div v-if="dropdownVisible" class="">
      <div class="py-1 absolute right-0 z-10 mt-4 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-green-100 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-white/20 focus:outline-none">
        <div v-for="variable in variables" :key="variable" class="pl-3 pr-4 py-2 text-xs flex flex-row font-medium text-green-700 cursor-pointer hover:bg-green-50" @click="selectVariable(variable)">
          <BoltIcon class="h-3 w-3 mr-1 fill-green-700" viewBox="0 0 12 12" aria-hidden="true"></BoltIcon>
          {{ variable }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { BoltIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/solid';

const props = defineProps({
  variables: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  targetElementId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const dropdownVisible = ref(false);
const inputField = ref(null);

const toggleDropdown = () => {
  if (!dropdownVisible.value && inputField.value) {
    inputField.value.focus();
  }
  dropdownVisible.value = !dropdownVisible.value;
};

const selectVariable = (variable) => {
  const inputEl = inputField.value;

  if (!inputEl) {
    console.error(`Input field with id ${props.targetElementId} not found.`);
    return;
  }

  const variableLabel = document.createElement('span');
  variableLabel.className =
    'inline-flex items-center gap-x-0.5 rounded-md bg-green-100 px-2 py-1 text-xs font-medium text-green-700 ring-1 ring-inset ring-green-600/20';
  variableLabel.innerHTML = 
    `${variable}
    <button type="button" class="group relative -mr-1 h-3.5 w-3.5 rounded-sm hover:bg-green-600/20">
      <span class="sr-only">Remove</span>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="h-3.5 w-3.5 stroke-green-700/50 group-hover:stroke-green-700/75">
        <path d="M4 4l6 6m0-6l-6 6" />
      </svg>
      <span class="absolute -inset-1"></span>
    </button>`;

  variableLabel.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
  variableLabel.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    variableLabel.remove();
  });

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(variableLabel);
    range.collapse(false);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  } else {
    inputEl.appendChild(variableLabel);
  }

  dropdownVisible.value = false;
};

onMounted(() => {
  inputField.value = document.getElementById(props.targetElementId);
});
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>


I tried a saveCursorPosition feature
